# TOC disappears when loading both 'tikz' and certain glossary commands. Memory issue?

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, memoir, memory

I am having an issue with a quite big project. The table of contents is empty and the error messages `No room for a new \write.` and `Bad number (16).` are thrown.

*Note*: I have included the code at the end of this question.

**Some background info:**

- Writing in OverLeaf
- Version 2022
- Compiler: pdfLaTeX
- Documentclass: memoir

**The issue:**

I have narrowed down the issue quite a lot and found that if I remove either one of the following blocks of code, the problem doesn't appear.

The `tikz` block (at the begining of the preamble):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
```

The `glossary` commands (at the end of the preamble):

```
\newglossary{introduktion}{sym1}{sbl1}{Faglig Introduktion}
\newglossary{ssh}{sym2}{sbl2}{Sandsynlighedsteori}
\newglossary{gruppe}{sym3}{sbl3}{Gruppeteori}
\newglossary{knudeteori}{sym5}{sbl5}{Knudeteori}
\newglossary{spil}{sym4}{sbl4}{Kombinatorisk Spilteori}
```

In fact, it is only necessary to remove a single one of the `\newglossary` commands for the problem to go away.

This leads me to believe that it might be some kind of memory problem? If so, how do I fix it?

## My code

This is my code. I also have an empty file named `Symboler.tex` in my `setup` directory. I have included my whole preamble as I thought it might be relevant if this is in fact a memory issue.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%Nødvendig for danske bogstaver
\usepackage[danish]{babel}%Sørger for at ting LaTeX gør automatisk er på dansk
\usepackage[twoside, inner=38mm, outer=38mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}%Fyldtekst, til brug under test af layoutet
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%Tillader eps filer
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 %undgår at fodnoter bliver spilittet op.
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % til at få figurer i tekst
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % til at importere/sammensætte pdf-filer
\usepackage{icomma}
%Fonts:
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Tikz:
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% Matematik ting
\usepackage{amsthm}% til theorems, definitions osv. i matematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % til visse matematik-symboler såsom \blacksquare
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools,wasysym}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} %For mathscr font
\usepackage{bm} % bold math
\usepackage{pifont}
\providecommand{\parbreak}{\\[10pt]}
\newcommand\lcm{\text{lcm}}
\renewcommand{\gcd}{\text{sfd}}
\renewcommand{\lcm}{\text{mfm}}
\renewcommand{\varnothing}{\emptyset}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\let\modstrid\lightning%Modstridslyn
\let\oldphi\phi
\let\oldepsilon\epsilon
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\renewcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
%disjoint union start
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\cupdot}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@cupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@cupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\cup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\cup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \sbox0{$\m@th#1\cdot$}%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0 %
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box0\hidewidth
  }%
}

\providecommand*{\bigcupdot}{%
  \mathop{%
    \vphantom{\bigcup}%
    \mathpalette\@bigcupdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@bigcupdot}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\bigcup$\cr
    \sbox0{$#1\bigcup$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0 %
    \advance\dimen@ by -\dp0 %
    \sbox0{\scalebox{2}{$\m@th#1\cdot$}}%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht0 %
    \dimen@=.5\dimen@
    \hidewidth\raise\dimen@\box0\hidewidth
  }%
}
\makeatother
%disjoint union en

%Referencer
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Tillader links
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\usepackage[danish]{cleveref}
%\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\cref{#1}}
% Sætter format af resultatet af \cref
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2(#1)#3}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{#3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
\crefname{equation}{ligning}{ligningerne}
\Crefname{equation}{Ligning}{Ligningerne}
\crefname{section}{afsnit}{afsnitene}
\Crefname{section}{Afsnit}{Afsnitene}
\crefname{figure}{figur}{figurene}
\Crefname{figure}{Figur}{Figurene}
\crefname{table}{tabel}{tabellerne}
\Crefname{table}{Tabel}{Tabellerne}
\crefname{opgave}{opgave}{opgaverne}
\Crefname{opgave}{Opgave}{Opgaverne}
\crefname{delopgave}{delopgave}{delopgaverne}
\Crefname{delopgave}{Delopgave}{Delopgaverne}

% definition af matematiske environments
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Sætning}[section]
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Sætning}
\crefname{theorem}{sætning}{sætninger}
\newaliascnt{lemma}{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{lemma}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmaer}
\newaliascnt{proposition}{theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}
\aliascntresetthe{proposition}
\crefname{proposition}{proposition}{propositioner}
\newaliascnt{corollary}{theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Korollar}
\newtheorem*{corollary*}{Korollar}
\aliascntresetthe{corollary}
\crefname{corollary}{korollar}{korollarer}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newaliascnt{definition}{theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}
\aliascntresetthe{definition}
\crefname{definition}{definition}{definitioner}
\newaliascnt{example}{theorem}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Eksempel}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Eksempel}
\aliascntresetthe{example}
\crefname{example}{eksempel}{eksempler}
\let\Oldendexample\endexample%
\def\endexample{\hfill$\circ$\Oldendexample}%
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Bemærkning}
\newtheorem*{remark*}{Bemærkning}
\newtheorem{metode}{Metode}
% definition af matematiske environments SLUT

%Headings
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
\createmark{chapter}{right}{nonumber}{\chaptername\ }{. \ }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \space}}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\rightmark}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{\thepage}{}{}
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{\thepage}{}{}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

%Fjerner kapitelnummerering fra sektioner
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

%Pagestyles:
\makepagestyle{mainpagestyle}
\makeheadrule{mainpagestyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{mainpagestyle}{\thepage}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{mainpagestyle}{\itshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{mainpagestyle}{
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\makeatother

\makepagestyle{refpagestyle}
\makeheadrule{refpagestyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{refpagestyle}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{refpagestyle}{}{}{\thepage}
%SLUT pagestyles

%Litteraturliste, index og symbolliste
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Kilder.bib}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]
%Så der ikke er konflikt mellem glossaries og memoir
\let\printglossary\relax 
\let\theglossary\relax
\let\endtheglossary\relax
%
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary{introduktion}{sym1}{sbl1}{Faglig Introduktion}
\newglossary{ssh}{sym2}{sbl2}{Sandsynlighedsteori}
\newglossary{gruppe}{sym3}{sbl3}{Gruppeteori}
\newglossary{knudeteori}{sym5}{sbl5}{Knudeteori}
\newglossary{spil}{sym4}{sbl4}{Kombinatorisk Spilteori}

\setglossarysection{section}
\renewcommand*{\glsclearpage}{} 
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

\newglossarystyle{symbolliste}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]%
       \hspace{1cm}##3\glspostdescription\space ##5}%
}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{setup/Symboler}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}\label{cha:One}
test
\end{document}
```

---

**Added by daleif**: Here is a much shorter example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Tillader links
\usepackage[danish]{cleveref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossary{introduktion}{sym1}{sbl1}{Faglig Introduktion}
\newglossary{ssh}{sym2}{sbl2}{Sandsynlighedsteori}
\newglossary{gruppe}{sym3}{sbl3}{Gruppeteori}
\newglossary{knudeteori}{sym5}{sbl5}{Knudeteori}
\newglossary{spil}{sym4}{sbl4}{Kombinatorisk Spilteori}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get the example as a single file such that others don't have to recreate your file/folder structure. That would also eliminate `subfile`.

Comment: @daleif thanks for suggestion. I have done that now.

Comment: Note that this still needs `\loadglsentries{setup/Symboler}`, but it can be removed for the error to manifest

Comment: Why exactly are you making a separate symbol list for several subjects. That costs a write slot on each.

Comment: @daleif because I would like the symbol list to be divided into five different headlines. Can this be done differently? What is a write slot?

Comment: LaTeX can only write to a limited number of files at the same time. And those 5 symbol lists brings it over the limit. You should probably look at the glossaries manual. I would assume that Nicola has provided a solution for that. We can probably make your example much shorter.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add a much shorter example. Not 100% sure why `pdfplots` takes a write slot. The example is very close to the limit. Note that I removed the `makeidx` package as it is already in `memoir`.

Comment: BTW: everything works fine if you change the engine from `pdflatex` to `lualatex` which does not have the same limit on the number of simultaneous write slots.

Comment: Thank you so much @daleif! I'll use LuaLaTeX (this project is based on another one where for some reason LuaLaTeX didn't work) and try to figure out a more elegant way of making those symbol lists!